# How do I center specific content without affecting the rest?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to programming but so far I'm addicted to it! I've looked on this site before posting my own question. I have found part of what I looked for but after trying few codes around, it didn't work so I thought about breaking the ice and asking for help!

Note: I'm using Kompozer.

What I try to attempt: I want the header and the footers to be full width while keeping the rest centered. I also want the white space below the footer to be full width just like at the top of the header. See this [example](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/fullscreen-backgrounds-with-centered-content).

Compared to that website, my website is yes centered but there is white space on each side and a bit of it below my footer. I hope I'm being clear enough for you to give me a hand! Thanks a lot!

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  #wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1156px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="headers">
      <div id="left">
        <div id="h1">
          <div style="text-align: left;">
            <div style="text-align: left;">
              <img style="width: 27px; height: 27px;" alt="" src="images/phone-icon-hi.png" align="top" vspace="5">+1-844-Meb-Zone&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <img style="width: 27px; height: 27px;" alt="" src="images/icon-mail-grey-150x150.png" align="top" vspace="5">support@meb-zone.com
              <br>
            </div>
            &nbsp;</div>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <div style="text-align: right;" id="h2">
          <img style="width: 33px; height: 33px;" alt="" src="images/lightbulb-grey.png" align="top" vspace="5">Try Our Customer Rewards Program &amp; Save Money on every order!
          <img style="width: 33px; height: 33px;" alt="" src="images/lightbulb-grey.png" align="top" vspace="5">
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menus">
      <div id="left">
        <div id="m1">
          <div style="text-align: center;">
            <div style="text-align: left;">
              <img style="width: 384px; height: 76px;" alt="" src="logo/LGO2015_2.png" align="middle">
              <br>
            </div>
            <br>
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navigations">
      <div id="left">
        <div style="text-align: center;" id="nav1">
          <div style="text-align: left;">HomeStoreBlogContactFAQ
            <br>
          </div>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <div style="text-align: right;" id="n2">
          <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" alt="" src="images/user.png" align="top" vspace="5">My Account
          <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" alt="" src="images/basic1-136_heart_favorite_list-128.png" align="top" vspace="5">My wishlist
          <img style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" alt="" src="images/36.png" align="top" vspace="5">Checkout
          <img style="width: 21px; height: 21px;" alt="" src="images/checkout-empty-128.png" align="top" vspace="5">Cart
          <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" alt="" src="images/protection_lock-512.png" align="top" vspace="5">Login
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: left;">
      <img style="width: 289px; height: 289px;" alt="" src="images/260277245_f6dca38e3413.jpg">
      <img style="width: 289px; height: 289px;" alt="" src="images/260277245_f6dca38e3413.jpg">
      <img style="width: 289px; height: 289px;" alt="" src="images/260277245_f6dca38e3413.jpg">
      <img style="width: 289px; height: 289px;" alt="" src="images/260277245_f6dca38e3413.jpg">
      <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="store_content">
      <div id="left_st">
        <div id="category">category left</div>
      </div>
      <div id="right_st">
        <div id="products">products left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footers">
      <div id="left">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <div style="text-align: left;">SERVICE
            <br>Contact Us
            <br>Blog
            <br>FAQ's
            <br>Customer Rewards Program
            <br>
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <div style="text-align: right;" id="f2">ABOUT MEB ZONE
          <br>Shipping &amp; Payment
          <br>Terms Of Service
          <br>Return Policy
          <br>Privacy Policy
          <br>Company Information
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom_footer">
      <br>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        Copyright © 2015 Meb Zone.com All rights Reserved.
        <br>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Isolate and include in the question only the specific part of your code you're having a problem with.

Comment: Thanks Nit. I did make some changes :)

Comment: can you put your code on jsfiddle with complete layout. as you have mention footer & header must be lie on top and bottom and rest should be lie center. so for center make div margin 0 auto with fixed width.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/155yb8h3/embedded/result/

As you can see, everything is center but the headers and the footers need to be full width leaving no space at the top of header and below the footer. Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/155yb8h3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is from the body.

Try this:

```
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

or this..

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0"> 
   (all your stuff here) 
</body>
```

Comment: First thanks for your reply! My code is actually  set to 0 padding and 0 margin. I thought maybe the issue is with where I place the ''wrap div''? I just don't know what to do... I'm a bit clueless!

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the `#wrap` is for. Try setting the `#wrap` width to `100%` instead of `1156px`.

Comment: The #wrap is for centering the content. Problem is, I want the background of my headers and footers to be full width without affecting the other parts. Here see what I'm trying to say: http://jsfiddle.net/155yb8h3/embedded/result/

As you can see, everything is center but the headers and the footers need to be full width leaving no space at the top of header and below the footer. Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/155yb8h3/